# How to fix html sitemap error on Google search console

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap

I have a problem with my sitemap, all my submitted URLs does not contain a "noindex" Tag, but google keeps saying that we are in 2019 the last crawl for my sitemap was in 2018! how to fix that and re-submit my sitemap?.

[image]

This is my `robots.txt` file:

[image]

Comment: Try a live test to confirm they are not noindexed. Then Submit to index.

Comment: Try browsing your XML file and using Developer Tools (F12 in your browser) to see if there's a noindex tag somewhere in the body of the output.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath yes my HTML sitemap has noindex tag, why I get the error? i never send my sitemap.html to google or should i remove the no index tag?

Comment: @Trebor yes my sitemap.html has noindex,follow tag? is that's normal, how to i fix the error?

Comment: Remove the nonindex tag, then resubmit to Google.  That should solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise this is for your XML sitemap. It does not need to be indexed, just submit it as a sitemap.